# Can I have two seperate state functions?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

For example, I hold my states in

`state: initialState()`

However, I reset this state with a button after some time. Is it possible to add another state that doesn't reset? I'd like to push the current state before reset to an array. So I could have a list of removed states in the history.
How should I approach this?

Comment: Can you share some more code? Is this Vuex related (state management library)? It could be that this is just a trivial question requiring a trivial solution. in other words, just code exactly what you are suggesting.

Comment: I can't add anymore code because I have no idea how to do this. As I said, I hold state in the initialState() function. I need seperate state in the same store that doesn't reset.

Comment: are you updating both states or do you just need an immutable initial state object to initialize the one you update/reset?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you mean. But this might do the the trick:

```
state: initialState(),
stateHistory:[initialState()]
```

And then you can do this before resetting

```
stateHistory.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state))) // creates a deepy copy of your current state
resetState() // reset the state after storing old state
```